# Scanner Canon DR-2020 U network

Tags: networking, usb, installation, ethernet, scanner

I bought a scanner ([Canon DR-2020 U](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/products/scanners/document_scanners/imageformula_dr_2020u_universal_workgroup_scanner)), but it doesn't have the network card.

How can I make this a network scanner?

I can hook the scanner to a computer that is on most of the time, but is it possible to connect the scanner with a router and use it with the ethernet network?

Comment: Connect it to any Windows machine then configured the WIndows machine to share the scanner.  [This](http://superuser.com/questions/81454/can-i-use-a-scanner-connected-to-another-computer-on-my-computer) question might also be of some help.

Comment: If the scanner doesn't have network capabilities, you can't just add a peripheral on like you can on a console.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the nicest way to do this is to install the USB scanner onto one machine and then share the scanner over TCP/IP using something like the 
[Network Twain Engine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nttwain/). (Free - Open Source)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a network ready scanner, so it would not be easily connected to Ethernet.

A solution I have used non-network scanners is to connect the scanner to a PC that is on the network and have all scans saved to a network share. Then each person who scans something can go to the network shared folder to retrieve their scan.

In your case, you can use Canon's [CaptureOnTouch](http://www.usa.canon.com/CUSA/assets/app/pdf/ISG/Scanner/Capture_OnTouch_Brochure_read_only.pdf) feature to make scanning simple.