# Printer/Scanner over Network: Windows sees it for printing, but not for scanning

Tags: windows-10, printer, lan, network-printer, scanner

I set up my `SCX-4623` Samsung printer by plugging the USB cable into my router. From there, I used [these instructions](https://karalius.wordpress.com/2014/10/22/manually-set-up-usb-printer-on-the-network-for-asus-rt-n66u/) to have Windows 10 be able to print to it over the network.

This works beautifully, over both wired (PCs) and wireless (laptop) connections. However, when I try to use Windows Fax & Scan in order to use the scanner, Windows claims that there aren't any scanners available:

[image: No scanners were detected]

Is there anything I can do to coax Windows into believing that the scanner, in fact, exists? The scanner works fine if I take the USB cable and connect the printer directly to the PC/laptop. But over the network it's a no-go.

Comment: The printer and the scanner are, to the computer, two different devices. If you wish to access the scanner over the network you must share it. Also, many scanners do not support scanning over the network. Most scanners you purchase at the store are not capable of this.

Comment: Can you put the correct printer make and model... doing a search for what you've written doesn't result in a printer/scanner so I'm not sure the printer you're using... I wonder if it's related tot he fact the device is connected via USB to your router. I also wonder if you may need to install the printer/scanner software as there is no real "open" network scanner protocol apart from TWAIN but your scanner manufacturer would probably have a proprietary connectivity where their software can communicate with the scanner better than using Windows built-in functionality. Samsung aren't easy.

Comment: Are there any options for scanning on the device itself? For instance, my home printer/scanner gives me the option to choose what network device to scan too, from the scanner. I have an HP program for my printer/scanner that opens on the selected computer I have scanned to.

Comment: @Kinnectus done. I put the router model in by mistake. The printer model is updated now (It's an SCX-4623).

Comment: According to http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00043750/ you have a software installed called "Samsung Scan and Fax Manager" - this should allow your computer to see and use the network scan functionality - it should scan your network and find your device. I've experienced Samsung network scan devices before and they're quite hideous (much like many other manufacturers, in all honesty) and they all tend to use some proprietary protocol or function to perform network scanning.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/81454/can-i-use-a-scanner-connected-to-another-computer-on-my-computer

Answer (score 2):

The printer and the scanner are, to the computer, two different devices. If you wish to access the scanner over the network you must share it from the host computer and install it on the client computers.

Just installing the shared printer will NOT provide the scanning capability of that piece of equipment.

Also, many scanners do not support scanning over the network. Most scanners you purchase at the store are not capable of this. Unless your scanner specifically states that it supports scanning over a network connection or share, it probably cannot do this.

Comment: man.. I hate giving you a point for some 4 year old post! (+1) ... but still a very good post.  You are the guy I love to hate. 8^P

Comment: Do we all have more and less favorite fellow members of this community? I'd guess yes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your printer does not support remote scanning. Most printers does not have remote scanner capabilities unless, there is an instruction on manual.